# Not able to run Sonar Scan on the Code due to java cant be indexed twice issue

Tags: maven, plugins, build, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

** We are working on to enable sonar-scan for our java code. but while running the maven command , we are facing the below issue. PFB the sample pom.xml,Command tried and error occurred
Command:**

```
 mvn clean -U -e org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.it.com/ -Dsonar.att.motsid=1254 -Dsonar.view.type=dev -Dsonar.login=3345566443 -Dsonar.projectName=xtest -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.tests=. '-Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**' '-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/**' -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/ -Dsonar.userHome=/home/m1234/.m2/repository_nexus -Dsonar.projectKey=xtest
```

**Error:**

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project common: File core/src/main/java/com/directv/common/constants/CommonConstants.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project commonFilecore/src/main/java/com/common/constants/CommonConstants.java can't be i.ndexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files`

Please help in resolving the error!  **

Comment: Why did you set dozens of `sonar.*` properties? Maven Scanner is smart and generates them. You shouldn't specify any parameters manually if you don't understand how they work. Finally, you see this problem, because you set `sonar.sources` and `sonar.tests` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by "duplicated" module in a project.  You should not include the same submodule in two diferent projects or make sure that you dont have two project (submodules) with the same group and artefact id.

If you want to share one submodule between two projects exclude the submodule scan for one project by specifiing the submodule in sonar exlude files or you can use maven parametr for excluding the submodule from build (mvn -pl '!exclude-module' ) .